# Создание рпг игры на php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Создаю текстовую RPG игру на PHP.

На данный момент занимаюсь разработкой инвентаря.

Как правило инвентарь делается по принципу drag and drop (его можно сделать на js), но как можно сделать так чтобы допустим из таблицы условного сундука пользователь перемещал предмет таблицу в рюкзака (во одну из клеток), и при этом в базе данных mysql в таблице `backpack` сразу записывались данные нового предмета, который мы перетащили из одного поля в другое.

Есть ли какие нибудь идеи как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Есть ли у вас аккаунт на gitHub? Очень интересно посмотреть, что в итоге получается

Comment: При помощи ajax можно без перезагрузки отправить запрос к php, который обновит значения в бд: [ajax](https://ruseller.com/jquery.php?id=11)

Answer (score 13):

Как-то так?

```js
let items = document.querySelectorAll('.grid div');
let el;
items.forEach(e => {
  e.id = 'id_' + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2);
  e.draggable = true;
  e.ondragstart = () => {
    el = e;
    el.style.transform = 'scale(0.5)';
  };
  e.ondragend = () => el.style.transform = 'scale(1)';
});

document.querySelectorAll('.grid').forEach(e => {
  e.ondragover = ev => ev.preventDefault();
  e.ondrop = ev => {
    e.append(el)
    console.log('move_to_' + e.id + '/' + el.id);
  };
})
```

```css
.grid {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  border: solid;
}

.grid div {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: solid;
  float: left;
  margin: 3px 0 0 3px;
  text-align:center;
  line-height: 30px;
  transition:0.1s;
}
```

```html
<div id=chest class="grid">
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div> 
</div>
<div id=bag class="grid">
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: да так, только как это можно свзять еще с php чтобы когда допустим закидываешь какие то элементы в сетку эти элементы запросом добавлялись в базу данных

Comment: заменить console.log на fetch