# Как перетаскивать картинку из блока в блок?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, drag-n-drop

Как можно перетаскивать картинку из блока в блок?

```css
body {
  background: lightskyblue;
}

.fill {
  background-image: url('https://wdesk.ru/_ph/209/2/68767157.jpg');
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 160px;
  width: 160px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: solid 3px royalblue;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"><div class="fill"></div></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Наверно речь идёт  о `Droppable` ?  https://jqueryui.com/droppable/

Comment: [HTML Drag and Drop API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1019215/188366

Comment: https://bevacqua.github.io/dragula/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Вариант с перетаскиванием элементов по клику](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1114525/31280)

Вариант с перетаскиванием элементов с зажатой клавишей мыши:

```js
const fill = document.querySelector('.fill');
const empties = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
fill.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart);
fill.addEventListener('dragend', dragEnd);
for (const box of empties) {
  box.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver);
  box.addEventListener('dragenter', dragEnter);
  box.addEventListener('dragleave', dragLeave);
  box.addEventListener('drop', dragDrop);
}
function dragStart() {
  this.className += ' hold';
  setTimeout(() => (this.className = 'invisible'), 0);
}
function dragEnd() {
  this.className = 'fill';
}
function dragOver(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}
function dragEnter(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.className += ' hover';
}
function dragLeave() {
  this.className = 'box';
}
function dragDrop() {
  this.className = 'box';
  this.append(fill);
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: lightskyblue;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: aliceblue;
  border: solid 3px royalblue;
}

.fill {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  cursor: move;
  background-image: url('https://wdesk.ru/_ph/209/2/68767157.jpg');
}

.hover {
  background: lightskyblue;
  border-style: dashed;
}

.hold {
  border: solid 5px #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"><div class="fill" draggable="true"></div></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Нужно ознакомиться с [HTML Drag and Drop API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API)

В примере в `dataTransfer` происходит запись `id`, который у `div` с картинкой. Затем в `ondrop` этот `div` "перереносится" в новый контейнер через `appendChild`. Т.е. по факту мы переносим не саму картинку, а только `id` в текстовом виде.

```js
function allowDrop(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}

function drag(e) {
  e.dataTransfer.setData("text", e.target.id);
}

function drop(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const data = e.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  e.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

```css
body {
  background: lightskyblue;
}

.fill {
  background-image: url('https://wdesk.ru/_ph/209/2/68767157.jpg');
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 160px;
  width: 160px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: solid 3px royalblue;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
  <div id="draggable" class="fill" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"></div>
</div>
<div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
```

Comment: спасибо за ваш ответ!